# Phonetic programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

Many of us coders, programmers and developers struggle with repetitive stress injuries, carpal tunnel, etc.

I've been curious about introducing voice control into my workflow in order to save myself some stress.

This has led me to my current question: Would it be possible or practical to implement a programming language (or superset of an existing language) which was primarily phonetic, and hence well suited to programming by voice?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It seems an interesting question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is programming language that is non-visual … possible?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/163811/is-programming-language-that-is-non-visual-possible)

Comment: Well, the most difficult part would be punctuation, and Victor Borge [solved that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bpIbdZhrzA).

Comment: If we use Victor's system we'll need windshield wipers for our monitors!

Comment: related: [Programming with voice recogition software](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148859/1033)

Comment: Somebody should enhance the Victor system towards the typical operator constructs found in programming languages. All those -> <> :: and so on. I'm especially curious how curly braces would sound.

Comment: @thorstenmüller surely the whole point of a *phonetic* programming language is you wouldn't pick syntax that was hard to pronounce in the first place.

Comment: I struggle to get voice recognition to work on email and documeantion. That's the brunt of my typing.

Answer (score 4):

A phonetic programming language is certainly possible, [SKI combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) give you a Turing complete language, and I don't think there can be any doubt that 'S', 'K' and 'I' are phonetic. With a restricted language like this there is even room to replace open and close brackets with something phonetic, maybe 'C' and 'D'. Of course actually using Turing tar pit languages is not something most people want to do.

The more interesting point is, is it practical to develop this way, with a 'real' phonetic language, as far as I know this is somewhat unknown.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution to solve puntuation and complex structure issues would be to phonetize a stack-based language such as Postscript.

The vocal editor could implement multiple modes, like vi: insert mode for saying the program and command mode for navigating and functions such as copy-paste, text search...

Comment: I was just about to add something about Forth to my answer, so have a +1 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a strong need for a programming language specialized for this.

However there is a need for alternative input methods for current programming languages.

Here's a presentation by Tavis Rudd about writing code using voice recognition.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI

He wrote python which might be easier to write this way than c for instance, so your mileage may vary depending on your preferred programming language.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible or practical to implement a programming language (..) which was primarily phonetic

Possible: probably.

Practical: probably not, your vocal chords would suffer even faster under the stress then you would get carpal tunnel.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back that up, or is it purely speculation?

Comment: @MattFenwick I typed 14 hours a day, my mother talks 8 hours a day. My fingers ache every few months, nothing that stops me. Her voice hurts after longer than usual days, and is "lost" every few weeks.